# Firebase Notification not sent from console

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase notification is not working properly with a specific project.

If I sent notification from the console to all devices it did not work.

If I tried to send a notification via REST. its returns with the below response.

```
{
    "multicast_id": ....,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "InvalidRegistration"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Update : 2**

I have created another project on the firebase console, delete resources and keys from the old project, then I have set up a new android application in the new project.

The result was the same, not receiving any notification The rest result was also the same.

But.
When I add another android application in the same project, then I was able to send notifications from a console-specific to that app, also from the rest API using token.

when I tried the original application token, I have the error. I am not able to find the issue ?. the registration part and initialization part was the same in the application.

Manifest Looks like.

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/purple_700" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />

    <service
        android:name=".CustomFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

**App.java**

```
public class App extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id),"X1",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
    }
}
```

Token Generate.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete() called with: task = [" + task + "]");
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete() called with: task = [" + task.getResult() + "]");
                }
            }
        });
```

I have tried the same code with different projects and it's working fine.
I don't know what's wrong!.

Comment: I too was facing this for long